# Using Baer's criterion for abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-homomorphism, injective-module

I am currently working through the chapters on injectivity in Donald Passman's *A Course in Ring Theory*, and have run into conceptual difficulty while attempting one of the exercises. I am trying to prove that a group homomorphism $\sigma:A\to B$, with both groups abelian, is injective or surjective iff $\hat\sigma:B^*\to A^*$ is surjective or injective respectively. For any abelian group $G$ we define $G^*=\operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$. We define $\hat\sigma(\theta)=\theta\sigma$ (function composition). For notational convenience let us here define $D:=\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$

I have been able to prove most directions, but have not quite completed proving that $\sigma$ being injective means that $\hat\sigma$ is surjective. To that end I fixed some $\theta\in A^*$. Now as $\sigma$ is injective, $\sigma^{-1}:\sigma(A)\to A$ is well defined. Thus we can define the map $\phi:=\theta\sigma^{-1}:\sigma(A)\to D$. If we can extend $\phi$ to a map $\tilde\phi$ acting on all of $B$ then we'd be done, for $\hat\sigma \tilde\phi=\theta$. (In fact $\hat\sigma\phi=\theta$, but we do not know whether $\phi\in B^*$). Now I suspect that somehow I can use Baer's criterion to get the desired extension, because $D$ is a divisible group, hence injective. The crux of my problem lies in the fact that to use it in the form presented in Passman, I need $\sigma(A)$ to be somehow identified with a right ideal of the ring $\mathbb Z$, and $B$ with $\mathbb Z$ itself, but I am unsure how to do that. I would appreciate help in knowing why I can extend $\phi$.

Comment: Have you proved every other direction, and this is the $\textit{only}$ one missing?

Comment: You seem to be relying on a characterization of injective $R$-modules as being those $R$-modules $M$ such that, for every ideal $I$ of $R$, every homomorphism $I\to M$ extends to a homomorphism $R\to M$. There's an equivalent characterization that says, for every $R$-module $Y$ and every submodule $X$of $Y$, every homomorphism $X\to M$ extends to a homomorphism $Y\to M$. (Usually, the second version is taken as the definition of "injective" and the first is a theorem.) The second characterization is deducible from the first via Zorn's Lemma, and it makes your question easy.

Comment: @AndreasBlass My definition of injectivity is exactly the one you pointed out. My prior training has mostly been in analysis, so I tried to prove surjectivity as I normally would, which in this setting of injective modules is the incorrect way. I just need to practice more and get in the habit of thinking in terms of commutative diagrams and functors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that $D$ is injective, then you know that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(-,D)$ is an exact functor.
Thus if $0 \to A \to B$ is exact, then $B^* \to A^* \to 0$ is exact.

Comment: Oh geeze, this is a much more elegant approach, thank you. However, I am still interested whether my approach would work. Do you happen to know whether my homomorphism could be extended?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to take the liberty of using $\sigma^*$ instead if $\hat{\sigma}$.

Since you mentioned Baer's criterion, I am assuming you know about injective modules. If $\sigma$ is injective then you can use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$  [is injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module). Namely, given $\theta \in A^*$, there exists $\theta'\in B^*$ such that $\theta = \theta'\sigma = \sigma^*(\theta')$.

Comment: I like your first answer, as it is more elegant than mine. However, I am not required to prove that $\sigma$ injective $\implies$ $\sigma^*$ injective. In fact I do not think that this is the case at all.

Comment: If we just take the first and the third statement, you're implying that any injective homomorphism of abelian groups is surjective.

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos Well, I know. That is why I started with "Assuming...". I think I misunderstood the question.